# special_values in scorecardpy.woebin error

Tags: python

I'd like to use "special_values" for function woebin in module scorecardpy on my data but it doesn't work. So I've found some example but I've got the same error.
Code:

```
import scorecardpy as sc
dat = sc.germancredit()
dt_s = sc.var_filter(dat, y="creditability")
train, test = sc.split_df(dt_s, 'creditability').values()
bins = sc.woebin(dt_s, y="creditability")
special_values = {
      'credit.amount': [2600, 9960, "6850%,%missing"],
      'purpose': ["education", "others%,%missing"]
    }
breaks_adj = {
    'age.in.years': [26, 35, 40],
    'other.debtors.or.guarantors': ["none", "co-applicant%,%guarantor"]
}
bins_adj = sc.woebin(dt_s, y="creditability", breaks_list=breaks_adj,special_values=special_values)
```

There appears an error:
MergeError: Can only pass argument "on" OR "left_index" and "right_index", not a combination of both.
Could You help me ? Do You have any idea why it doesn't work ?
Without "special_values" it's ok.

causes the issue:

```
bins_adj = sc.woebin(dt_s, y="creditability", breaks_list=breaks_adj,special_values=special_values) -
```

I restarted kernel and I got another error :(
bins_adj = sc.woebin(dt_s, y="creditability", breaks_list=breaks_adj,special_values=special_values)
[INFO] creating woe binning ...
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
bins_adj = sc.woebin(dt_s, y="creditability", breaks_list=breaks_adj,special_values=special_values)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scorecardpy\woebin.py", line 958, in woebin
bins[x_i] = woebin2(

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scorecardpy\woebin.py", line 722, in woebin2
bin_list = woebin2_tree(

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scorecardpy\woebin.py", line 484, in woebin2_tree
bin_list = woebin2_init_bin(dtm, init_count_distr=init_count_distr, breaks=breaks, spl_val=spl_val)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scorecardpy\woebin.py", line 276, in woebin2_init_bin
dtm_binsv_list = dtm_binning_sv(dtm, breaks, spl_val)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scorecardpy\woebin.py", line 108, in dtm_binning_sv
sv_df['value'] = sv_df['value'].astype(dtm['value'].dtypes)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5877, in astype
new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 631, in astype
return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 427, in apply
applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 673, in astype
values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1074, in astype_nansafe
return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)

File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 619, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: Could you post which line is causing the issue, as well as the error stack trace?

Comment: Please edit your post instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the pandas version. Downgrading pandas helped.

Comment: It might help future readers to identify the version you used initially and the version that works. Thanks.